# Remove In-App Billing test ID's history for retesting

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I m testing in-app billing on test ids but once i purchase i cannot purchase it again because the response is "you have already owned product" but i need to purchase it again for testing. So how can i do it? The Merchant Account also does not contain purchase data.

Comment: You can consume it in the purchase complete event or wait.  The test IDs are reset automatically every day or so.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to consume the purchased product in the code. After that you can purchase it again.

```
IabHelper.consume(purchase)
```